# Entity Framework Junction(ish) Table Mapping Code FIrst

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How does one map a junction table with values in EF v6.2?

Let's say you have entities named "Item1", "Item2" and another entity of them mapped:

```
public class Item1
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MapItem> { get; set; }
}

public class Item2
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MapItem> { get; set; }
}

public class MapItem
{
    public long Item1ID {get; set;} //PK, FK
    public int Item2ID {get; set;} //PK, FK

    public decimal Value {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual Item1 {get; set;}
    public virtual Item2 {get; set;}
}
```

EDMX automatically generates this but how would I build this with code-first / FluentAPI to build an accessible collection of the `MapItem` entity?

I've tried updating the mapped entity to use `[Key(Order = 1)]` and `[Key(Order = 2)]` on the PK & FK values for `MapItem`.

This seems like a weird scenario considering it's not a true junction table of 2 entities, but also holds value as well.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable and valid to have a "junction" table that represents a relationship between two tables contain additional information about that relationship - that's not a "weird scenario", but quite a common one, actually. Think about e.g. the duration of validity of that relationship - if two entities are related only for a certain period of time. But, if you have such a junction table that does contain additional data, EF cannot automagically handle that for you anymore - you need to treat it like a regular table/entity and do your own mapping

Comment: @marc_s I agree as that is how I'm using it now. I am asking how to do that mapping in code first, it is not able to pick up the MapItem entity.

Answer (score 0):

Here I was able to get it resolved using FluentAPI.

Here I modified the entity class:

```
public class MapItem
{
    [Key(Order = 1)]
    public long Item1ID {get; set;} //PK, FK

    [Key(Order = 2)]
    public int Item2ID {get; set;} //PK, FK

    public decimal Value {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual Item1 {get; set;}
    public virtual Item2 {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the relationship builder:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MapItem>().HasKey(q => new
 {
        q.Item1ID, q.Item2ID
 });
​
 modelBuilder.Entity<MapItem>().HasRequired(q => q.Item1).WithMany(q => q.MapItem).HasForeignKey(q => q.Item1ID);
 modelBuilder.Entity<MapItem>().HasRequired(q => q.Item2).WithMany(q => q.MapItem).HasForeignKey(q => q.Item2ID);
```

The crucial part was the "HasKey" method which correctly mapped the entities.